# LinkedIn find person id from person name

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-j, spring-social-linkedin

I have a list of LinkedIn profile URLs and by proxy a list of person names/vanity names. I am trying to invoke the REST API and need each of their person IDs. How can I get the person ID from the name/URL?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of finding person id using username, name or url. 
Facebook has done the same, PID is required in facebook.
User can fetch the data only when PERSONID is available, this prevent any misuse of their api or stealing of people data.